# R and Matlab Dendograms Structures

Tags: r, matlab, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I know very little about R, but I need to convert the dendrogram resulted from hierarchical clustering in matlab into R dendrogram structure. The following table shows the dendrogram resulted from hierarchical clustering in matlab function; where the first and the second column are the IDs for the objects or branches, and the third column is the distance.

[image]

Is there a way to map this table (or matlab dendrogram) into R dendrogram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easiest way for you to have a dendrogram in R is to use some intermediate results from your matlab analysis instead of using the final table.

Assuming that you have a dissimilarity matrix called `Diss_Mat` (which you should definitely evaluate at some point of your matlab algorithm), you could do the following

```
DIST_Mat=as.dist(Diss_Mat) #create a dist type object
dendro=as.dendrogram(hclust(DIST_Mat))
```

where with the second line you perform the hierarchical clustering in R and then you create a dendrogram type object.

Comment: what is the structure of 'Diss_Mat' matrix should be?

Comment: It is a dissimilarity matrix, like the one you can obtain by using the `pdist` function. [link](http://it.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) 
Such a matrix should be positive valued and symmetric (at least if you're using a proper distance) and contain information related to the distance between each couple of points.

Comment: I'm using 'custom distance' to measure the similarity between the data points.  suppose we have 3 points(a,b,c). I'm assuming that the matrix should look like this: m = [D(a,b); D(a,c); D(b,c)] . Then, I find DIST_Mat=as.dist(m). Is that right?

Comment: Your matrix would be like this: 
[0, D(a,b), D(a,c); D(b,a),0,D(b,c); D(c,a),D(c,b),0] 
By calling `as.dist()` in R you will get the `dist` type which is needed for the `hclust` function, as written above. Hope you'll find it useful.